# Moving the origin point of an armature

Tags: armature

I am trying to move a character to a different place in the scene, is there a way to move its original origin point (armature) with it.Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doesn't moving armature instead of character,  move also character if it's parented alraedy? Can't test it as im not at the computer atm.

Comment: I might of put my question incorrectly, It's the origin point where the armature and rig was originally created. When i move the rig to a different position its origin point stays.

Comment: I meant character and rig

Answer (score 0):

If you drag character, rig stays where it is
[image: Dont drag character]

If you drag armature instead, character follows it
[image: Drag rig instead]

Comment: I might of put my question incorrectly, It's the origin point where the armature and rig was originally created. When i move the rig to a different position its origin point stays.

Comment: I meant character and rig

Answer (score 0):

You press Ctrl+A to set the transforms. So move it, press ctrl+A, and click translate.

However: Best practices is to create a root bone, or master bone that you use to move your character in pose mode.

**To move the Origin of the selected object:** CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+C Moves the origin. You can then select from multiple choices on where you want the origin to be. I personally would use the 3d cursor as you can align it to where ever you want.

Comment: I think I have been a bit stupid as i have a walk and jump animation on the rig/character which must be the problem (its only my second try at animation). Not sure if/how I can get that to follow too?

Comment: It leaves a blue dotted line that any path i set for the walk cycle is set to the origin point.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have created a walk cycle and are trying to repeat it over a path?

Comment: I updated my answer, it should be what you want.

Comment: Great thanks very much for your help and have a good day.

Comment: Did that answer your question and work for you?

Comment: Not really but I managed to work round. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Move the Armature itself (not the model), and move it in Object Mode instead of Edit Mode or Pose Mode.

What you're describing would happen if you're moving the rig without toggling into Object mode first. You can think of the Armature as being composed of a container (the Object), contents (the Armature), and deformations (Poses).

If you are in Edit Mode then you might move all of the contents to another location, but that hasn't actually moved the container. It's like having a very large box. You've moved everything away from the center of the box, but your box is still in the same place.

When you are in Object Mode, you can move the whole "container" to another part of the scene and all the "contents" will move inside it.

Usually, you toggle between Edit Mode and *the last mode you selected* with <kbd>tab</kbd>. You can also select a mode explicitly with this drop-down menu next to "Object" (ignore the radial menu for now): [image: Mode selection menu in the 3D viewport]

More in [The Manual.](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/modes.html)